# Django add multiple database NAME for different user

Tags: python, django

In my django project i have to differenziate database name by user. i would to create a table, or a field in user table with database name and in settings.py insert related values checking user connected, but i have two doubt:

1. How can i insert into DATABASES dict new variable?

   ```
   DATABASES = {
     'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.test.postgresql',
       'NAME': myvar,
       'USER': 'postgres',
       'PASSWORD': 'password',
       'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
       'PORT': '5432',
     }
   }
   ```
2. Settings.py is read before table and db instantiation, how is possible passing values after login?

There is another pythonic way to achieve this result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's is not thread safe way (web applications need to be thread safe) to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-tenant Django applications: altering database connection per request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721051/multi-tenant-django-applications-altering-database-connection-per-request)